# How to create a editable list like the playlist in Ipod?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, list, uitableview

In my Iphone App,which is a multiple view application using arc and storyboard, i want to create a editable list, like the playlist in the iphone's integrated ipod.
when i click on the edit button there should be little red '-' images left of the items texts and there also should appear a '+' button on the navigation bar where i can add new items to the list.

You see it should be similar to the playlists in the ipod.
Does anybody knows any tutorial about that or something else? I googled for 2 hours but found nothing -.-

I would be very happy if you can help me with this

Thanks

Comment: any tutorial of `UITableView` would be good for you to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the lastest Xcode, try making a 'Master Detail' application.

That should provide with you with basic editing functionality in a `UITableView`.

Comment: i have already a multiple views application with storyboard... i wil add that to my question

Comment: Well, still.. copy the delegate methods from the simple application to the class for your `UITableViewController` and you should have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UITableView`, for the small '-' and the '+' you can create buttons with the intended task as actions. If you want the specific red '-' buttons then I think they are available in the ios sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The '+' and '-' signs are accessories for the `tableViewCell`. So to set them, you need to set the `accessoryType` property of the `UITablewViewCell`. If you look at the class reference, there's a list of them, including the buttons. What I would also do is have a bool value for each cell, and have the `accessoryType` be '+' or '-' depending on the value of the bool, and have the value itself change every time the user touches the cell. That way the sign will switch every time a cell is touched, and at the end you can go through and save or discard the things in each cell based on it's bool value.